# Bootstrap 4.0 Carousel not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

the bootstrap carousel in bootstrap 4.0 is not working, i have checked everything and written the code 100% the same:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="First slide"> 
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The images simply show up below each other and the left and right buttons like links, as if bootstrap isn't even referenced.

Comment: Did you properly include the appropriate js for the bootstrap carousel?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

i have insert here and it's working. you has check jquery and bootstrap js+css?

Comment: It worked, it turns out that the template i downloaded had a <nocode> tag around the css imports that stopped the bootstrap css file from being imported porperly, thanks for your help anyway